# Android Studio cannot resolve nested imports in dart files

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, import, package

To explain my problem with an example:

I added the dart package [`carousel_slider`](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) to my Flutter project. According to the package documentation, all that's needed to use the package is

`import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';`

This file is importing related files on its own, like `carousel_controller.dart` and `carousel_options.dart`. However, my Android Studio cannot resolve these imports and says "Undefined class 'CarouselController'" when I try to use `CarouselController` without explicitly importing the respective dart file myself.

How can I tell my Android Studio to resolve these "nested" imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, there was an issue with the version of the package I had installed.
At first, I had `^2.0.0` in my pubspec. So I hardcoded it to `2.2.1` and ran `flutter pub upgrade` and now Android Studio resolves everything properly.